# How to Read Json String

Tags: javascript, json

I am NEW IN json ,How can i read given JSON string in JavaScript.I want Pass associated array in High Chart .

```
{"getTemperatureResult":"[[\"{name: 'Tokyo',data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6]}\",\"{name: 'New York',data: [-0.2, 0.8, 5.7, 11.3, 17.0, 22.0, 24.8, 24.1, 20.1, 14.1, 8.6, 2.5]}\",\"{name: 'Berlin',data: [-0.9, 0.6, 3.5, 8.4, 13.5, 17.0, 18.6, 17.9, 14.3, 9.0, 3.9, 1.0]}\",\"{name: 'London',data: [3.9, 4.2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]}\"],[\"Jan\",\"Feb\",\"Mar\",\"Apr\",\"May\",\"Jun\",\"July\",\"Aug\",\"Sep\",\"Oct\",\"Nov\",\"Dec\"]]"}
```

Comment: `data = JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: EXACT duplicate of [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632/how-to-parse-json-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3):

"How can I read given JSON String in JavaScript".

The verb "read" is a bit ambiguous, but if you wanted to evaluate it, you can use

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

You need to encapsulate the JSON in a quote that isn't used within your JSON to actually parse it, but looking at your code, there is no easy way to do it.. My advice to you is -

That JSON at some point is returned from some service as a string.  Do a global replace on all single quotes, to replace them with a `\"` because as it stands, there is no way to evaluate it with single or double quotes.

A little tip on JSON too - be sure to run JSON through a json lint to make sure that it is valid.. trouble can stem from not having properly formatted JSON.

Use http://jsonlint.com for validating it.

Comment: Actually you've produced as syntax errors since the string *does* contain apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
var myObject = JSON.parse(your_JSON_variable);
```

Answer (score 1):

Read:

```
var obj=JSON.parse(jsonstring);

obj.getTemperatureResult// contains the city array
```

back to string

```
JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't always count on the browser having `JSON` functions available out-of-the-box.

I'd suggest either using [`jQuery`'s `$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) function or tapping into the excellent [`json2` solution](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: [Reference on browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FJSON#Browser_compatibility) for `JSON`.

Comment: yeah .. jquery is slow.jQuery is a polyfill for older browsers and just slows down everything.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is odd. Inside the object you've nested another JSON string - instead of the array directly which it presents.

```
// Assuming your got the string from a XHR response directly:
var obj = JSON.parse(response);
// or you've got the object directly embedded in your script:
var obj = {"getTemperatureResult":"[[…]]"};

// then do:
var arr = JSON.parse(obj.getTemperatureResult);
```